# handleShortCutItem navigationBar inside a tabBar

Tags: ios, shortcut, 3dtouch

I am trying to implement 3D Touch shortcuts into my app, but I'm not sure how to handle the fact that i have a Navigation Bar inside a Tab Bar, if i declare the rootViewController as my navigationBar then my shortcut works, BUT then when the shortCut screen is dismissed, i have no tab bar. Here is how my storyboard is linked up, I have no idea what to do here.

[image: Red is where i am trying to go]

I am trying to get to the red.

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func handleShortCutItem(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {
    var handled = false

    if let shortcutType = ShortcutType.init(rawValue: shortcutItem.type) {

        let tabBarController = UITabBarController()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let rootController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTabBar") as! UITabBarController

        let tradesNav = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TradeNavigation")

 //            if self.window != nil {
            self.window!.rootViewController = rootController
 //            }


        // Get root navigation view controller and its first controller
        let rootNavigationViewController = window!.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
        let rootViewController = rootNavigationViewController?.viewControllers.first as UIViewController?
        // Pop to root view controller so segue can be handled

        rootNavigationViewController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

        switch shortcutType {
        case .newTrade:
            tradesNav.performSegueWithIdentifier("newTradeModal", sender: nil)
            handled = true
        }
    }
    return handled
}
```